# Плавная анимация появления языков

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как мне сделать плавную анимацию для появления языков?

```css
.langdrop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.langbtn {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.langdrop-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  z-index: 120;
}

.langdrop-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.langdrop-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.langdrop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #669999;
}

.langdrop:hover .langdrop-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="langdrop">
  <div class="langbtn" id='lang'>RU</div>
  <div class="langdrop-content">
    <a class="langdrop-link"> RU </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> EN </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> UK </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется плавное изменение высоты, то это можно сделать через `max-height`:

```css
.langdrop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.langbtn {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.langdrop-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  z-index: 120;
}

.langdrop-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.langdrop-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.langdrop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #669999;
}

.langdrop:hover .langdrop-content {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="langdrop">
  <div class="langbtn" id='lang'>RU</div>
  <div class="langdrop-content">
    <a class="langdrop-link"> RU </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> EN </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> UK </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: то что надо! спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вот мой вариант "плавной анимации", раз вы не указали, какую конкретно вам надо.

```css
.langdrop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.langbtn {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.langdrop-content {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  z-index: 120;
  transition: opacity .4s ease; /* ==== МОЖНО ПОМЕНЯТЬ ДЛЯ АНИМАЦИИ ПОЯВЛЕНИЯ ==== */
}

.langdrop-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.langdrop-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.langdrop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #669999;
}

.langdrop:hover .langdrop-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="langdrop">
  <div class="langbtn" id='lang'>RU</div>
  <div class="langdrop-content">
    <a class="langdrop-link"> RU </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> EN </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> UK </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Что за магия?** 
У вас блок с языками скрывается через `display:block`, я же заменил на `opacity`, так как это св-во можно анимировать через `transition`.

Comment: да , забыл указать какой. Хотелось бы чтобы высота всего langdrop-content менялась плавно от 0 до 100%.

Comment: visibility: hidden ещё надо

Answer (score 0):

```css
.langdrop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.langbtn {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.langdrop-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 120;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.langdrop-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.langdrop-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.langdrop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #669999;
}

.langdrop:hover .langdrop-content {
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="langdrop">
  <div class="langbtn" id='lang'>RU</div>
  <div class="langdrop-content">
    <a class="langdrop-link"> RU </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> EN </a>
    <a class="langdrop-link"> UK </a>
  </div>
</div>
```